# ASP.NET Web Application on IIS 7.5 can not write file to application folder

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I know this question has been asked and answered however i cannot seem to get my instance to work.

I have a web application which needs to create and save a (.pdf) file to a local directory (call it 'pub'). I believe this is a permissions issue, not a code issue, for my application writes the file just fine on my development box (Vista - IIS 7). When I execute on my production server (2008 R2 - IIS 7.5) the application fails gracefully with no error, but the file is not written.

The application is running in its own AppPool (call it MyAppPool).

I have set Anonymous Authentication to 'Application Pool Identity'.

.NET Trust level is set to 'Full'.

Originally i set permissions on the pub directory allowing IIS_IUSR RW permissions (still set).
When that did not work research told me to use ICACLS to set 'IIS AppPool/MyAppPool' on the pub for RW permissions, which i have, but still no go.

What the heck might I be missing?

Comment: Try using impersonation in the web config.

Comment: Nope. That didn't do it either.